# Unable to Install asammdf in Python 3.8 32-bit Virtual Environment

Tags: python, windows-7, virtualenv, python-3.8, asammdf

I am trying to create a 32-bit Python virtual environment using Python 3.8 in Visual Studio Code on a Windows system. I want to install the asammdf library in this environment. Here's what I've done so far:

I've created the virtual environment with the command:

```
py -3.8-32 -m venv env
```

I activated the virtual environment with:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

I tried installing asammdf using pip with:

```
pip install asammdf
```

At this point, the installation process fails with the error message:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for asammdf
Failed to build asammdf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for asammdf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

It seems the failure is linked to a missing requirement for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater. However, I have already installed the latest Microsoft C++ Build Tools following the official guide.

**What's puzzling is that I've successfully installed asammdf in a Python 3.8 64-bit virtual environment following the same process. This issue only arises with the 32-bit environment.**

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to install asammdf in a 32-bit Python virtual environment? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.